# Automatically reposition views after UITextview resizes - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

For a simple example lets say I have a UITextView with a Button underneath it. These two controls are siblings both embedded in a parent UIView.

I now change the text within the UITextView and resize it accordingly. Is there a way to make the button automatically move to have the same relative distance to the bottom of the UITextView? This may seem trivial for this case, but I will have a longer hierarchy with multiple UITextViews that change and it would be nice not to have to calculate the height of every object manually.

Comment: you should accept correct answers to your previous question. it'll help you to get answers in the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be with a table view: if you place each of your text views within its own table view cell, the table view will automatically calculate its total height from individual calls to its delegate’s `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method and lay itself out accordingly. Whenever the height of one of your text views needs to change, you can call `-reloadData` on the table view to make it lay itself out again. A disadvantage of this approach is that it’s really difficult to animate the height changes; if that’s essential to the effect you’re going for, I’m afraid you’re stuck with doing the entire layout manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try the autoresizingMask property of UIView.

Comment: From what I can tell, that will only resize children views. I need it to resize sibling views.

Comment: then you need to manage it one step higher in the view hierarchy - if it's a custom class, `layoutSubviews` is a good place to do it. - - - there are newer resizing strategies coming in newer OS X releases, they may trickle to iOS